# Is it correct and natural to say "establish policy according to which"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you tell me if the following sentence sounds correct and natural?

> We should **establish a policy according to which** people would be fined for throwing garbage in the street.

If it's not natural what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: "according to which" looks a bit excessive (or rather formal) to me. "We should establish a no-littering policy" might work, but policy doesn't necessarily imply fining people who break it.

Comment: Agreed. People are fined for breaking laws (or bylaws) rather than ignoring policies. A **no littering** policy would be concerned with ways to discourage littering, which might include making it an offence, punishable with fines.